# django filtering on a field in a foreign key object

Tags: python, django

Given the following models from the django polls tutorial:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently'


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

I want to be able exclude questions without and choices like suggested in the tutorial. I've been playing around with Filter but I can't figure it out, I tried:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), choice__count__gt=0)
```

but I'm getting

```
Relation fields do not support nested lookups
```

How can I filter by Questions that do not have any Choices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use like below

```
from django.db.models import Count

......

def get_queryset(self):
    return Question.objects.annotate(num_choice=Count('choice')).filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), num_choice=0)
```

Comment: This seems like its even better because it allows me to filter by questions with any arbitrary number of choices, like 2 or more, whereas the other answers only tell me if there are some or 0 choices

Answer (score 2):

Use choice__isnull=True, where choice is the related_name.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), choice__isnull=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `choice__isnull=False` instead of count like

```
return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), 
                               choice__isnull=False)
```

Note that you may get duplicated records which you can consolidate using `.distinct()`.

Comment: This works, but if I can't use count then if I wanted to change it to filter by questions that only have some arbitrary number of choices how could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

i would change the models to something like:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    choices = models.ManyToManyField('Choice')
    ...

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    ...
```

query will be like

```
questions = Question.objects.annotate(num_of_choices=Count('choices')).filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), num_of_choices=0)
```

Comment: And now you have two relationships between these objects and one of them is redundant. Instead you could just add an explicit related_name on the FK in Choice.question of 'choices'.